# Is it possible to use two cameras in after effects for motion tracing

Tags: after-effects

I want one camera behind me (only for motion tracking), and one before (I want to show the scene only from the front view, but I need the camera behind for "wings" motion tracking.

Comment: Sounds like you need to investigate motion capture, rather than motion tracking.